# Python TypeError when saving data to file

Tags: python, string, format, typeerror

I am trying to work on the area of code that saves the select users data to file. I am using a code that saves the best 3 scores from a user, or atleast I think it does. But it currently brings up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sfawcett\Desktop\MainCode", line 189, in <module>
    scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"]), "," "etime") )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The code:

```
if pclass == 1:
    SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
    MAX_SCORES = 3

    try: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "r+")
    except IOError: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # File not exists
    actualScoresTable = []

    for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")

        # This block changes all of the scores in `tmp` to int's instead of str's
        for index, score in enumerate(tmp[1:]):
            tmp[1+index] = int(score) 

        actualScoresTable.append({
                                "name": tmp[0],
                                "scores": tmp[1:],
                                })
    scoresFile.close()

    new = True
    for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
        if record["name"] == pname:
            actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(correct)
            if len(record["scores"]) > MAX_SCORES:
                actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].pop(0) # OR del actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]
            new = False
            break
    if new:
        actualScoresTable.append({
                                 "name": pname,
                                 "scores": [correct], # This makes sure it's in a list
                                 })

    scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
    for record in actualScoresTable:

        for index, score in enumerate(record["scores"]):
            record["scores"][index] = str(score)

        # Run up `help(str.join)` for more information
        scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"]), "," "etime") )

    scoresFile.close()
elif pclass == 2:
    inFile = open("bscores.csv", 'a')
    inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
    inFile.close()
    inFile = open("bscores.csv", 'r')
    print(inFile.read())
elif pclass == 3:
    inFile = open("cscores.csv", 'a')
    inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
    inFile.close()
    inFile = open("cscores.csv", 'r')
    print(inFile.read(sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[0]))))
else:
    print("Sorry we can not save your data as the class you entered is 1, 2 or 3.")
```

Comment: change `scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"]), "," "etime") )` to `scoresFile.write( "%s,%s,etime\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"])) )`

Comment: Try in your Python prompt to simply play with the formatted string until you get it right, i.e, `%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"]), "," "etime")` as others point out you don't have enough placeholders for your arguments.  In fact it would be a good time for you to look into the new format syntax, with a function attached to a string holding the arguments.  That way the relation between the number of arguments and their placeholders become clearer.  Like this, `{name:s}, {scores:d}, etime".format(name=record["name"],scores=record["scores"])`

Answer (score 0):

Your format string has place for two values, but you are passing in *three*:

```
("%s,%s\n" %
# 1  2
 (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"]), "," "etime"))
#     1                     2                    3
```

You appear to be reinventing CSV writing; use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead:

```
with open("cscores.csv", 'ab') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # build one list
    row = [record["name"]] + record["scores"] + ['etime']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Oh Sorry I wasn't supposed to include that last bit, that was my previous testing and I'm trying to write this one as a txt file to improve it. I can't get the variable "etime" to save as the time which is the time it took them to do the task. Do I have to save it as ["etime"]? Also how can I use this data to sort itself from highest to lowest when I view scores?

Comment: @PythonBeginner: I assumed you wanted to append the literal text `etime` in that column; the CSV sample produces a list with separate entries for `record['name']` and each of the elements of `record['scores']`, followed by that string. If you need sorted data, then use `sorted()` to produce a sorted list.

Comment: I have fixed the current with the placeholder issue, but now I have tried this.

scoresFile.write( "%s,%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"], "," , ["etime"])))

And now I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sfawcett\Desktop\MainCode", line 161, in <module>
    tmp[1+index] = int(score)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'etime'.
What does this mean?
@MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0):

I see only two placeholder `%s` marks there, and three items in the list following it. Perhaps formatted like this it is more obvious:

```
scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (
  record["name"], 
  ",".join(record["scores"]), 
   "," "etime"
))
```

The string "," "etime" becomes a single string ",etime" which is the third parameter, should this be inside the join bracket perhaps?